# Parse query Sessions returns does not return all sessions

Tags: javascript, session, parse-platform

When i try to query the Class Session it only returns sessions from my username 
this returns only 6 items when I have 10 sessions in my dashboard. I just want to get all the sessions

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Session);
    query.find({
        success: function (results) {
            console.log(results);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I can get sessions table content by using this.

```
let query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Session);
query.find({useMasterKey:true}).then((data) => console.log('sessions: ', data));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Session);
    query.find({
        success: function (results) {
            console.log(results);
        }, useMasterKey:true
    });
```

Not all sessions are public read for all users.  This happens automatically in the background.  When you don't pass the master key or a user's session token into a query, save, fetch, delete, or create call, and you have CLP / ACL settings that don't allow public read / write access, you won't get the desired results.  For queries, it'll still return all the objects you do have find access for.  For saves, fetches, creates, and destroys, if you don't have write permissions, the fail will save.

Comment: I recommend getting used to ACL and CLPs now, and implementing them all through your app as you go! It's so much harder to go back and do this, and it's a strongly recommended security practice.  Without any ACLs / CLPs, anyone who gets a hold of your app (easiest on web, possible on iOS and Android) can get your client key / app id / server url, and then get access to ALL unprotected data in your database. Not only that, but they can change data if there are public write permissions.  Users should only be able to change the data they directly set. And even then, wrap in a server call instead